# unable to save images to style folder in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

when I attempt to view images in drupal 8 I am not able to see in any style , image style folder has been created however images are not saving in this folder I set permission 777 clear cache many time but did not work

Answer (score 0):

"image style folder has been created" . You need to create the style first,(Configuration-> media -> image style) and then associate it with your custom image field in "manage display" (structure -> content type -> 'yourcontenttype' -> manage display).

PS: if you are invoking your image directly through the twig template, must add some code, like this:

```
<img src={{ 'myimage.jpg' | image_style('image_style_machine_name') }}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply  image style has been created already under configuration ,but image is not going to save in style folder

Comment: So, i would check media settings, and/or watchdog/dblog. There must be some clue out there.